# Terraform: InvalidParameterException: PutSubscriptionFilter operation cannot work with destinationArn for vendor es

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to replicate the AWS console feature where I can simply click on a log group, and choose stream on ES, and choose one of my managed ES.

I thought `aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter` was what I was looking for. And even though the doc said it's only Kinesis and Lambda, I thought to myself "maybe the documentation is old/incomplete"

so I tried

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "whatever" {                                                                                                                                                                      
  name            = "lambda_logs_to_es"                                                                                                                                                                           
  role_arn        = aws_iam_role.my_lamda_role.arn                                                                                                                                                                            
  log_group_name  = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.my_log_group.name                                                                                                                                                                
  filter_pattern  = ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  destination_arn = "arn:aws:es:eu-west-3:585399047133:domain/my-es"                                                                                                                          
}
```

and unsurprisingly it tells me

```
Terraform  InvalidParameterException: PutSubscriptionFilter operation cannot work with destinationArn for vendor es
```

so is there a simple way with terraform to replicate this feature, without needing to write my own lambda, to forward the log of my other lambda (lambda-ception) to ES ? (which was one of the reason I chose ES from AWS rather than installing my own, the feeling it will better integrates with other AWS services) ?

i.e is there an already (if possible backed by AWS) lambda and terrafor module using said lambda, to do this feature ?

Comment: How do you think about `fluentd` ? It is simple way to input log to ES. See : [a github repo](https://github.com/gnokoheat/fluentd-aws-elasticsearch-service)

Comment: The  problems are : my lambda are only executed once in a while so it defeats the purpose imho if i have a ec2  (or eks etc) with a fluentd container sitting there for nothing 99% of the time, especially my other services have already rsyslog configured to forward to es.  The other problem is that the fluentd you are linking does not seem to be able to read directly cloudwatch log stream right ?

Comment: I've not worked with these AWS features for a _long_ time so I expect I'm probably not remembering all of the details right, but I have a memory that the path to getting logs into ElasticSearch is to have Cloudwatch Logs write to Kinesis Firehose and then Kinesis Firehose in turn write into ElasticSearch. Kinesis Firehose serves as a sort of buffer to avoid the data store writes creating backpressure into the log delivery service. I'm sorry I don't remember more details, but hopefully that's a useful breadcrumb for more research...

Comment: Even I am struck with this issue. @allan.simon were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: yes I need to find time to put a nicely summarized solution, but basically i need to create a lambda that forward cloudwatch logs to ES, the code of said lambda being the one you get from the wizard in the amazon console

Comment: @allan.simon can you post the solution to this one ? im also stuck with it.

Comment: @ShalomBalulu I've posted a very raw answer, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will edit the answer later with more code but long story short:

There's nothing magic, the click click you do in AWS console, actually create a lambda that will forward the logs to ES, there's no magic direct link with amazon managed elastic search.

so I actually ended up doing

```
#
# Create a lambda that will forward other lambda's logs
# to the VPC's elasticsearch, this whole configuration can be done
# manually though the "stream to elasticsearch" option when you
# choose where to stream a log group of cloudwatch
#

resource "aws_iam_role" "logs_to_es_lambda_role" {
  name = "logs_to_es_lambda_${local.env_type}"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_basic_role_to_logs_to_es" {
  role = aws_iam_role.logs_to_es_lambda_role.id
  # this policy permits to log in cloudwatch
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "access_vpc_role_to_logs_to_es" {
  role = aws_iam_role.logs_to_es_lambda_role.id
  # this policy permits the lambda to have access to the vpc (as the Elastic search
  # is only accessible from there
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "logs_to_es_log_group" {
  name              = "/aws/lambda/logs_to_es_lambda_role_${local.env_type}"
  retention_in_days = 7
}

resource "aws_security_group" "logs_to_es" {
  description = "allow all egress network for the lambda logs_to_es"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id
  name        = "lambda-${local.env_type}-logs-to-es"

  egress {
    protocol    = "-1"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name               = "lambda-${local.env_type}-logs-to-es"
    ManagedByTerraform = "true"
    EnvironmentType    = "${local.env_type}"
  }
}


data "archive_file" "logs_to_es_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "lambdas/logs_to_elasticsearch/logs_to_elasticsearch.js"
  output_path = "lambdas/logs_to_elasticsearch/logs_to_elasticsearch.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "logs_to_es" {

  filename         = data.archive_file.logs_to_es_zip.output_path
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.logs_to_es_zip.output_base64sha256
  function_name    = "logs_to_es_${local.env_type}"

  role    = aws_iam_role.logs_to_es_lambda_role.arn
  handler = "logs_to_elasticsearch.handler"

  timeout = 100

  runtime = "nodejs10.x"

  description = "${local.env_type} script that forwards cloudwatch logs of that VPC's lambda to ES"

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets
    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.logs_to_es.id
    ]
  }

  environment {
    variables = {
      ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT = aws_elasticsearch_domain.technical_logs.endpoint
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Environment        = local.env_type
    ManagedByTerraform = "true"
  }

  depends_on = [
    "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.attach_basic_role_to_logs_to_es",
    "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.access_vpc_role_to_logs_to_es",
    "aws_cloudwatch_log_group.logs_to_es_log_group",
  ]
}
```

the code of the lambda being

```
#
# Create a lambda that will forward other lambda's logs
# to the VPC's elasticsearch, this whole configuration can be done
# manually though the "stream to elasticsearch" option when you
# choose where to stream a log group of cloudwatch
#

resource "aws_iam_role" "logs_to_es_lambda_role" {
  name = "logs_to_es_lambda_${local.env_type}"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_basic_role_to_logs_to_es" {
  role = aws_iam_role.logs_to_es_lambda_role.id
  # this policy permits to log in cloudwatch
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "access_vpc_role_to_logs_to_es" {
  role = aws_iam_role.logs_to_es_lambda_role.id
  # this policy permits the lambda to have access to the vpc (as the Elastic search
  # is only accessible from there
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "logs_to_es_log_group" {
  name              = "/aws/lambda/logs_to_es_lambda_role_${local.env_type}"
  retention_in_days = 7
}

resource "aws_security_group" "logs_to_es" {
  description = "allow all egress network for the lambda logs_to_es"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id
  name        = "lambda-${local.env_type}-logs-to-es"

  egress {
    protocol    = "-1"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name               = "lambda-${local.env_type}-logs-to-es"
    ManagedByTerraform = "true"
    EnvironmentType    = "${local.env_type}"
  }
}


data "archive_file" "logs_to_es_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "lambdas/logs_to_elasticsearch/logs_to_elasticsearch.js"
  output_path = "lambdas/logs_to_elasticsearch/logs_to_elasticsearch.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "logs_to_es" {

  filename         = data.archive_file.logs_to_es_zip.output_path
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.logs_to_es_zip.output_base64sha256
  function_name    = "logs_to_es_${local.env_type}"

  role    = aws_iam_role.logs_to_es_lambda_role.arn
  handler = "logs_to_elasticsearch.handler"

  timeout = 100

  runtime = "nodejs10.x"

  description = "${local.env_type} script that forwards cloudwatch logs of that VPC's lambda to ES"

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets
    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.logs_to_es.id
    ]
  }

  environment {
    variables = {
      ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT = aws_elasticsearch_domain.technical_logs.endpoint
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Environment        = local.env_type
    ManagedByTerraform = "true"
  }

  depends_on = [
    "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.attach_basic_role_to_logs_to_es",
    "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.access_vpc_role_to_logs_to_es",
    "aws_cloudwatch_log_group.logs_to_es_log_group",
  ]
}
```

and then to use it , you just need to put that lambda ARN in the `aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter` ressource.

Comment: Thanks Allan! I will try it :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer here, @allan.simon!

Comment: hmm yes true,  copy paste mistake !

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @allan.simon's answer. Perhaps by mistake, he didn't post the lambda function's code in his answer, so I'm posting it here, for someone who may need it, to not generate it manually.

```
// v1.1.2
var https = require('https');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var endpoint = 'YOUR ENDPOINT HERE';

// Set this to true if you want to debug why data isn't making it to
// your Elasticsearch cluster. This will enable logging of failed items
// to CloudWatch Logs.
var logFailedResponses = false;

exports.handler = function(input, context) {
    // decode input from base64
    var zippedInput = new Buffer.from(input.awslogs.data, 'base64');

    // decompress the input
    zlib.gunzip(zippedInput, function(error, buffer) {
        if (error) { context.fail(error); return; }

        // parse the input from JSON
        var awslogsData = JSON.parse(buffer.toString('utf8'));

        // transform the input to Elasticsearch documents
        var elasticsearchBulkData = transform(awslogsData);

        // skip control messages
        if (!elasticsearchBulkData) {
            console.log('Received a control message');
            context.succeed('Control message handled successfully');
            return;
        }

        // post documents to the Amazon Elasticsearch Service
        post(elasticsearchBulkData, function(error, success, statusCode, failedItems) {
            console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify({
                "statusCode": statusCode
            }));

            if (error) {
                logFailure(error, failedItems);
                context.fail(JSON.stringify(error));
            } else {
                console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(success));
                context.succeed('Success');
            }
        });
    });
};

function transform(payload) {
    if (payload.messageType === 'CONTROL_MESSAGE') {
        return null;
    }

    var bulkRequestBody = '';

    payload.logEvents.forEach(function(logEvent) {
        var timestamp = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp);

        // index name format: cwl-YYYY.MM.DD
        var indexName = [
            'cwl-' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // year
            ('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
            ('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)          // day
        ].join('.');

        var source = buildSource(logEvent.message, logEvent.extractedFields);
        source['@id'] = logEvent.id;
        source['@timestamp'] = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp).toISOString();
        source['@message'] = logEvent.message;
        source['@owner'] = payload.owner;
        source['@log_group'] = payload.logGroup;
        source['@log_stream'] = payload.logStream;

        var action = { "index": {} };
        action.index._index = indexName;
        action.index._type = payload.logGroup;
        action.index._id = logEvent.id;

        bulkRequestBody += [
            JSON.stringify(action),
            JSON.stringify(source),
        ].join('\n') + '\n';
    });
    return bulkRequestBody;
}

function buildSource(message, extractedFields) {
    if (extractedFields) {
        var source = {};

        for (var key in extractedFields) {
            if (extractedFields.hasOwnProperty(key) && extractedFields[key]) {
                var value = extractedFields[key];

                if (isNumeric(value)) {
                    source[key] = 1 * value;
                    continue;
                }

                jsonSubString = extractJson(value);
                if (jsonSubString !== null) {
                    source['$' + key] = JSON.parse(jsonSubString);
                }

                source[key] = value;
            }
        }
        return source;
    }

    jsonSubString = extractJson(message);
    if (jsonSubString !== null) {
        return JSON.parse(jsonSubString);
    }

    return {};
}

function extractJson(message) {
    var jsonStart = message.indexOf('{');
    if (jsonStart < 0) return null;
    var jsonSubString = message.substring(jsonStart);
    return isValidJson(jsonSubString) ? jsonSubString : null;
}

function isValidJson(message) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(message);
    } catch (e) { return false; }
    return true;
}

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function post(body, callback) {
    var requestParams = buildRequest(endpoint, body);

    var request = https.request(requestParams, function(response) {
        var responseBody = '';
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            responseBody += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            var info = JSON.parse(responseBody);
            var failedItems;
            var success;
            var error;

            if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 299) {
                failedItems = info.items.filter(function(x) {
                    return x.index.status >= 300;
                });

                success = {
                    "attemptedItems": info.items.length,
                    "successfulItems": info.items.length - failedItems.length,
                    "failedItems": failedItems.length
                };
            }

            if (response.statusCode !== 200 || info.errors === true) {
                // prevents logging of failed entries, but allows logging
                // of other errors such as access restrictions
                delete info.items;
                error = {
                    statusCode: response.statusCode,
                    responseBody: info
                };
            }

            callback(error, success, response.statusCode, failedItems);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        callback(e);
    });
    request.end(requestParams.body);
}

function buildRequest(endpoint, body) {
    var endpointParts = endpoint.match(/^([^\.]+)\.?([^\.]*)\.?([^\.]*)\.amazonaws\.com$/);
    var region = endpointParts[2];
    var service = endpointParts[3];
    var datetime = (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[:\-]|\.\d{3}/g, '');
    var date = datetime.substr(0, 8);
    var kDate = hmac('AWS4' + process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, date);
    var kRegion = hmac(kDate, region);
    var kService = hmac(kRegion, service);
    var kSigning = hmac(kService, 'aws4_request');

    var request = {
        host: endpoint,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/_bulk',
        body: body,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Host': endpoint,
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
            'X-Amz-Security-Token': process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
            'X-Amz-Date': datetime
        }
    };

    var canonicalHeaders = Object.keys(request.headers)
        .sort(function(a, b) { return a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1; })
        .map(function(k) { return k.toLowerCase() + ':' + request.headers[k]; })
        .join('\n');

    var signedHeaders = Object.keys(request.headers)
        .map(function(k) { return k.toLowerCase(); })
        .sort()
        .join(';');

    var canonicalString = [
        request.method,
        request.path, '',
        canonicalHeaders, '',
        signedHeaders,
        hash(request.body, 'hex'),
    ].join('\n');

    var credentialString = [ date, region, service, 'aws4_request' ].join('/');

    var stringToSign = [
        'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
        datetime,
        credentialString,
        hash(canonicalString, 'hex')
    ] .join('\n');

    request.headers.Authorization = [
        'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' + process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID + '/' + credentialString,
        'SignedHeaders=' + signedHeaders,
        'Signature=' + hmac(kSigning, stringToSign, 'hex')
    ].join(', ');

    return request;
}

function hmac(key, str, encoding) {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(str, 'utf8').digest(encoding);
}

function hash(str, encoding) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(str, 'utf8').digest(encoding);
}

function logFailure(error, failedItems) {
    if (logFailedResponses) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));

        if (failedItems && failedItems.length > 0) {
            console.log("Failed Items: " +
                JSON.stringify(failedItems, null, 2));
        }
    }
}
```